# put labels on two specific marker in google maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I'm about to complete my project just some small stuff to do and I'd appreciate if someone could help me about this issue.
I want to put marker label'A' and 'B' on first and last marker but I don't know how to do this,I tried some solutions but that was not useful.
and this is my code snippet without complexity.

```
var dataModel;
var line = [];

polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: Coordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#00cccc'
            )};


 line.push(polyline);

            for (i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                line[i].setMap(null); //or line[i].setVisible(false);
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < Markers.length; j++) {
                Markers[j].setMap(null);
            }

            Markers = [];           

$.each(marker, function (index, value) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude),
                    map: map 
                });

                Markers.push(marker);
            });
```

[image: and this is a pic from what I've done,just want put an 'A' label on first marker and 'B' on the second.].imgur.com/Jkxcc.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MarkerLabel interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel)

You will have to add the label in the following way while creating the marker :

```
var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: -25.361, lng: 132.959},
      map: map,
      label: {
        text: 'A'
      }
    });
```

You can check the [Marker Label Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels) for a complete example

As per your requirement you will need to add 'A' for the first marker and 'B' for the second marker while you are iterating `dataModel`